# jquery to find a span by title and add a class to it. In SharePoint

Tags: jquery

I appologize I am not very versed in Javascript and jquery but what I need to do is find a span with a certain title "Title1" and add a class to that span.  I tried several different methods just looking at examples I found by googling but nothing has worked.  Anybody got a good example on how to do this.  Below is what I think should work?

```
$('span[@title="Title1"]').each(function(){ 
var $this = $(this); 
// attach the Padding Class
$this.addClass("paddingleft4");
} 
);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there are several different ways to try what you're doing, however I wouldn't recommend find elements by title.  Title's are generally meant to hold a string containing information pertinent to the user when they mouse over the element.  It would be far better to add a class to your spans before run-time and then search for those spans based on that pre-established class.

Of course, the simplest method is already shown:

```
$('span[title="Title1"]').addClass('paddingleft4');
```

However, you could also use a million different possiblities with jQuery's [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function.

As seen on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/sjTCn/), I make use of .filter by changing the text of spans that **don't** have *Title1* inthere title string.

After just reading your comment on your question, I thought i should mention some things in easy commented format:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // jquery equivilant to window.onload = function() { /* do work */ }
    // also = to jQuery's own #(document).ready(function() { /* do work */ })
    $(function() {

        $('span')   //  this is simple jquery call to create an object of all spans on document
        .filter(function(i) {   //  this tells jQuery to take those spans and filter out the ones that dont get returned on the inner function
            //  this is that function
            //  here i use it to see if the spans title
            //      contains the phrase "1L - Students"
            //      if not, then false is return and that
            //      item is removed from our initial jQuery object
            return $(this).attr("title") ? $(this).attr("title").indexOf("1L - Students") != -1 : false;
        })
        .each(function(i) { //  this .each is being used because i'm replace the TEXT of each span left in object with its TITLE string
            $(this).text($(this).attr("title"))
        });
    })
</script>
```

if span is created dynamically, maybe try placing script at end of body (see comments)

Comment: The spans are getting generated via a SharePoint control so I have no control over setting the class before run-time. It is a multiple select control with checkboxes and I only want a few of the items in the multi select to get the added class not all of them.  The method mentioned above is still not working though, I think the script may be running before the control gets rendered by SharePoint.

Comment: make sure you're including jQuery in your header, and run this script at the end of your page, or in the function that calls for your sharepoint object, i assume its an xml doc of somesort?

Comment: Thanks all for the help I got it working, The span wasnt there when the script was running so placing it in the bottom of the body did it.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: NP, glad I could be of help, maybe check me as answer?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `@` when using attribute selector and also you don't need to loop through all the element just call `addClass` jQuery will do the rest.

```
$('span[title="Title1"]').addClass('paddingleft4');
```

Comment: This is still not working, the title of the span is "1L - Students" with a dash and spaces, could this be throwing it off?

Comment: No, it should not create any issue with space and hyphen.